# How to use SauceOnDemand Plugin with Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, saucelabs

I have a freestyle Jenkins job with the Sauce OnDemand plugin installed.  That plugin provides UI so I can define which browser and devices I wish to test on in the Job config.  It works as expected.

Now I want to migrate my job to a Declarative Pipeline job.

The Pipeline Snippet generator, under the "sauce: Sauce" sample step, says I should do:

```
sauce('<guid for my saucelabs user>') {
    // some block
}
```

Does anyone what //some block should be that would allow me to specify the browsers I wish to test on?

I am not using node, I am using .NET.

What am I missing?

Comment: Has noone else had this problem?

Comment: I did find this reference on the saucelabs site but it seems to me to fall just short:  

https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Using+the+Sauce+Labs+Jenkins+Plugin+with+Jenkins+Pipeline 

I am expecting to see syntax where you can list platforms somehow.  Does anyone else know how to do this?